# can ament package depend on catkin package

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any clean way of having an ament package depend on a catkin package if, say, their workspaces are different but maybe the ament workspace is an overlay on the catkin workspace? The main problem I think we're seeing is if the catkin package has system dependencies(on for example Boost), the ament package can't properly link all the libraries exported from the catkin package that would normally be available in `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279269/can-ament-package-depend-on-catkin-package/) by [jlack](https://answers.ros.org/users/30932/jlack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried it, but in theory, yes. `ament` is just a kind of cmake project, and there are examples of how to use ROS 1 (and therefore catkin) from plain cmake and/or with make:

https://github.com/gerkey/ros1_external_use

If you apply these principles, you should be able to build an ament package on top of a catkin workspace, though it's not a "supported" use case and the tools/documentation don't cover this case at all, at least that I am aware of.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlack](https://answers.ros.org/users/30932/jlack/) on 2018-01-09**:
Yeah I was just wondering about how to keep from manually having to link my dependencies dependencies libraries without depending on `${catkin_LIBRARIES}`. I'm thinking maybe from the ament package I could use, `${catkin_pkg_name_LIBRARIES}` and those should contain the correct libraries